# why when I click on the event it only works sometimes and not always?

Tags: javascript, dom, contains, event-listener

```js
let addToCart = document.querySelectorAll('#app')

addToCart.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click',(e) => { 
    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('add-to-cart')) {
        console.log('click!')
    }
    
    })
})
```

I am working with dynamic buttons and template literals to make a shopping cart. I fetch to extract the information from mongo DB, but when I click the add request button it only works a few times.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `querySelectorAll('#app')`
The `#` means you want to get an `ID`, But `querySelectorAll` select mutiple `Id`s and document `HTML` accept only one `id` per page use instead `querySelector('#app')`.

```js
let app = document.querySelector('#app')

app.addEventListener('click',(e) => {    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('add-to-cart')) {
        console.log('click!')
    }  
})

// Alernative way using querySelectorAll 
/*
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');
[...btns].forEach(btn=>btn.addEventListener('click',()=>console.log('click!')))
*/
```

```html
<div id="app">
<li>
Item 1
<button class="add-to-cart">+</button>
</li>
<li>
Item 2
<button class="add-to-cart">+</button>
</li>
</div>
```